# Facebook Graph API does not return the shares field on some public Facebook posts that have more than 0 shares

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Some Facebook posts (like [this one](https://www.facebook.com/294260637288_10156602705717289)) have multiple shares. However, when querying the graph API, no shares field is returned (example [here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=294260637288_10156602705717289%3Ffields%3Dshares&version=v2.11)).

Many other posts on the same page (like [this](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=294260637288_10156603245307289%3Ffields%3Dshares&version=v2.11)) seem to return the shares field - which is the expected behaviour.

Any ideas what might be causing this behaviour, and how to get the shares for posts like the one highlighted above?

Comment: That looks weird indeed ... they are of type=link and status_type=shared_story, and I can’t spot any significant difference between the two posts that would explain this. Suggest you file a bug report, and ask them whether that’s a bug, or somehow intentional. https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: Thanks for the note. I [filed a bug](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1970801223160827/) yesterday. Will update this question as soon as I get a response.